# Restore from Time Machine backup from within macOS

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, restore, data-recovery

I want to restore a remote Time Machine backup on a fresh install of macOS.

From what I've read, you need to do this from the Recovery Mode (Command+R). However, the new Macbook Pro (2017) doesn't have an Ethernet socket and doesn't support USB-C to Ethernet adapter in Recovery Mode.

My only option is to restore over WiFi which will take 90+ hours... (1TB SSD)

So, is there a way for me to restore a Time Machine backup from within macOS (not Recovery Mode)? (this will allow me to use USB-C to Ethernet adapter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Migration Assistant.

On your new Mac:
Open Migration Assistant, which is in the Utilities folder of your Applications folder.
Click Continue.
When asked how you want to transfer your information, select the option to transfer from a Mac, Time Machine backup, or startup disk.
Click Continue.

Comment: I didn't know Migration Assistant existed, and could use remote Time Machine backups. Just reinstalling macOS now and will give it a try. I will report back.

Comment: If you are doing a fresh install, don't set up a user account. When the setup assistant asks if you want to import your data from another mac or backup, say YES and find your Time Machine backups. Also, what exactly do you mean by "remote" Time Machine?